# Heroku npm version with Strongloop buildpack

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, strongloop

So I have a project built on top of loopback.io. I have specified the node and npm versions within package.json.  However, for some odd reasons upon installation the server still seems to be using npm = 1.4.28. Thoughts on what else I need to do?  Right now I am assuming because of npm = 1.4.28, it is causing issue for lodash to install.

I did the usual for building Strongloop on heroku: heroku apps:create --buildpack https://github.com/strongloop/strongloop-buildpacks.git

```
"engines": {
    "node": "0.10.x",
    "npm": "2.x"
}
```

And the log from heroku upon git push

```
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! EEXIST, open '/app/.npm/ea4720da-app-npm-lodash-2-4-1-package-tgz.lock'
remote:        File exists: /app/.npm/ea4720da-app-npm-lodash-2-4-1-package-tgz.lock
remote:        Move it away, and try again. 
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-40-generic
remote:        npm ERR! command "/tmp/build_bf55002725acbaa28a6caabb58f75a77/vendor/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_bf55002725acbaa28a6caabb58f75a77/vendor/node/bin/npm" "install" "--production"
remote:        npm ERR! cwd /tmp/build_bf55002725acbaa28a6caabb58f75a77
remote:        npm ERR! node -v v0.10.35
remote:        npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
remote:        npm ERR! path /app/.npm/ea4720da-app-npm-lodash-2-4-1-package-tgz.lock
remote:        npm ERR! code EEXIST
remote:        npm ERR! errno 47
remote:        npm ERR! not ok code 0
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
```

Comment: Actually it didn't for me. I ended up updated the scripts and not using that build pack anymore. Then it picked up 2.x when installed. I didn't want to fight with the buildpack.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem by temporarily disabling Heroku's use of cache:

`heroku config:set NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false`

Push the build, then turn cache back on.